# Data Service is throwing mysterious exception: "Media type requires a '/' character"

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, iis-7.5

When loading ASP.NET pages on my site, the pages are occasionally failing and throwing exception in my logs:

```
Media type requires a '/' character
```

The full exception is as follows:

```
System.Data.Services.DataServiceException: Media type requires a '/' character.     at 
System.Data.Services.HttpProcessUtility.ReadMediaTypeAndSubtype(String text, Int32& 
textIndex, String& type, String& subType)     at 
System.Data.Services.HttpProcessUtility.MimeTypesFromAcceptHeader(String text)     at 
System.Data.Services.HttpProcessUtility.SelectMimeType(String acceptTypesText, String[] 
availableTypes)     at 
System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SelectResponseFormat(DataServiceHostWrapper host,     String 
acceptTypesText, Boolean entityTarget)     at 
System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SelectResponseFormatForType(RequestTargetKind 
targetKind, ResourceType resourceType, String acceptTypesText, String mimeType, 
IDataService service)     at 
System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription     description, 
IDataService dataService)     at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
```

After the failure occurs, if I hit F5 to refresh, the page loads normally. It will then fail again later if I try to reload but there doesn't appear to be any rhyme or reason why it's happening.

I've done a web search but had no luck in finding a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: did you tried it in a different browser?

Comment: I was experiencing it in Chrome 13 but currently not able to repro in IE or FF. However, since it's happening sporadically I can't be sure if it's browser related or not.  It seems unlikely to me that a browser compat issue would cause this.

Comment: Can you please paste the exception with newlines?

Comment: Let me know if that's better.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with you when posting an odata request to an odata producer.

Finally I resolved it by adding the header 'Accept' with empty value, which was omitted before.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Are you manually setting the MIME types on the page?  If so, can you post the code?  It sounds like you are setting them incorrectly.

Comment: I have a custom mime type setup in IIS for `text/cache-manifest` to files with extension `.appcache` for HTML5 local storage. It's set in IIS not at the page level.